# Municipal council "approves"/"accepts" secret documents

Tags: magna-carta, parliamentary-law

In Alberta, Canada the Municipal Government Act says:

> 180(1)  A council may act only by resolution or bylaw.

Our council emerged from an *in camera* session and passed a resolution:

> ... that Council accept Administration's report on the Legal Claim Defense Statement as presented.

The report was presented *in camera* and they refuse to give me the report or statement.

If they can "act" by "approving"/"accepting" secret documents it seems to be an "end run" around MGA(180).

I thought that the main point of the Magna Carta was "no secret decrees".

Do I have a right to this information without recourse to FOI?

Comment: The Magna Carta was a renegotiation of the relationship between a 13th-century king and his feudal barons; only three terms remain in force (freedom of the church in England, liberties of the city of London, and no one can be punished except by judgment of peers or by law of the land, not can justice be delayed or sold). I'm not sure why you think it could possibly be summarized as "no secret decrees."

Comment: I have very limited knowledge of Canadian laws, but it looks like the council did not approve of anything in camera. All approvals were done in public.

Comment: Is it just me, or is anyone else missing how any of this implies secrecy?